# How to perform line of codes if in my IF statement the button doesnt exist?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

With the help of the guy in here this code worked:

```
        boolean clickMore = true;
    while(clickMore == true) {
        List<WebElement> button1 = driver.findElements(By
                    .xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button"));
        if(button1.size()>0) {
            button1.get(0).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        }else {
            clickMore = false;

        }
        WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
        List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));
        System.out.println("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());
    }
```

Here is the case:

1. In the listview for example Account module listview, if I have 100's of records. This blocks of code above is working since I have the button "MORE". But when my listview is only 5records and there is no button displayed since there is no pagination. The code doesn't work.

Please help to which line of code should I modify for it to work that if there is no button to clicked for pagination it would still work.

Thank you!

Comment: As per code you are already checking that of there it no button then go to else , condition is there`if(button1.size()>0)` , what error you are getting if there is no button?

Comment: Sorry for getting back late. Here is the response if there is no button:
 
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: then try to put  `Thread.sleep(4000);` before `button1.get(0).click();`

Comment: button1.get(0).click(); <<< it means this button is not visible, you could check for visible before click it

Comment: Hi @HelpingHands , can we have a chat on this on a chat room, would like to clarify something about the code. Could you please send me a link ? -only if you have time

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82570/regarding-issue-of-element-not-visible

Answer (score 1):

you can either a) surround your button click with a try/catch block or b) first check is the button displayed.

Approach (a)

```
try {
  button1.click();
} catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
  clickMore = false;
}
```

or (b)

```
if(button1.isDisplayed()) {
  button1.click();
else {
  clickMore = false;
}
```

i would also recommend trying to use a more exact selector for the button, rather the accessing it by its list index.

Answer (score 0):

I explore my codes mentioned above and I find it a bit difficult. When im searching for the button1 through Xpath, it seems to be present even if it not viewed/visible on the front end. A friend of mind saisd maybe its an HTML problem.
So I tried it again but not using an xpath, I used the `linkText` and it worked.
Tip, try to use other functionalities not just by xpath or id, **try exploring the others I dont know how they differ exactly but from my experience there are some case that if you'll use xpath it sometimes doesn't work and i have to explore using the other one  for it to work.**

My code now is :

```
boolean clickMore = true;

    while(clickMore == true){

        List<WebElement> button1 = driver.findElements(By
                    .linkText("More gate meters and service points..."));
        System.out.println(button1.size());

        if(button1.size() > 0){

            button1.get(0).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);

        }else{

            clickMore = false;

        }

    }

    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));

    System.out.println("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());
}
```